# Mathematical term for vertical distance between highest and lowest points of a function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, terminology

### Mathematical term for vertical distance between highest and lowest points of a function?

---

**Context:**

---

Wikipedia lists 'Height' as the term for [twice the amplitude of a sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_height):

> For a sine wave, the wave height H is twice the amplitude

And another source gives ['max-min'](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra2/TrigGraphs/TGTrigVocab.html)
as the term for that distance:

[image]

---

**Question:**

---

*Is there any more mathematically specific term for the vertical distance between the lowest point and highest point of a function?*

---

**NB**

---

The reason I ask is because I wish to use such a term (if it exists) in a non mathematical paper, and it should be clear that I am referring to the height/max-min in a mathematical sense, and not in a general sense ('height', for example, *could* be misinterpreted by non-mathematicians as being the distance from y=0 to the function's peak).

Comment: How about "range"?

Comment: @MattiP. thanks! that's definitely less ambiguous than the other two terms, I will use that unless something better comes up. I am casting the net wide in my search... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CchyctRFrQ

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the word you are looking for is to do with the "Range" of a function, which is [defined as:](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/range-statistics-.html)

> The set of output values that a given function can take as its argument varies

Or (though not specifically relating to functions) as this:

> The difference between the lowest and highest values.

Either way, generally the difference between the maximum and minimum points is referred to as the "range" of the function.

Hope this helps!